# Exchange bool values between two Lists, C#

Tags: c#, list, collections, iteration

Help me to find a way to do the following, please:

I have two `List<bool>`.

First one contains different bool values, I know nothing about the length and content of the second one. I have to go through the first `List<bool>` and if I meet a true value I need to write it in the second `List<bool>` at the exactly same position where I met it in the first `List<bool>`.

For example, first list consists of false-false-true that means that I should write true at the third position of the second `List<bool>`, the second one should look like ...-...-true and if there was something on the ... position I should preserve it and if there was nothing there I should put false there.

Comment: any attempts to solve it by yourself?

Comment: It is very confusing how you are explaining your problem... please add more detail in what you want to do. It is also very unlikely to have a List<bool> to solve something.

Comment: What do you expect in the 2nd list for places where the 1st list contains `false` values?

Comment: " I know nothing about the length " you need to take care of the case that the second list is shorter than the first, otherwise you run into trouble

Comment: @MonZhu the OP specify that if there was nothing, false must be inserted instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, the only (little) difficulty is in the condition: `Math.Min(list1.Count, list2.Count)`:

```
List<bool> list1 = new List<bool>() { true, false, true, false };
List<bool> list2 = new List<bool>() { false };

...

// Math.Min(list1.Count, list2.Count): ...I know nothing about the length
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(list1.Count, list2.Count); ++i)
  if (list1[i])      // ... if I meet a true value
    list2[i] = true; // I need to write it in the second ... at the exactly same position
```

Test:

```
 // [true]
 Console.Write("[" + string.Join(", ", list2) + "]");
```

**Edit:** In case you want to *pad* `list2` with `false` to ensure that all `true` will be at their indexes:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; ++i)
    if (list1[i]) {
      if (i >= list2.Count) // do we want padding?
        list2.AddRange(new bool[i - list2.Count + 1]);

      list2[i] = true;
    }
```

Test:

```
 // [true, false, true]
 Console.Write("[" + string.Join(", ", list2) + "]");
```

Comment: Add curly brackets, your code quality will fail  :))

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstList = new List<bool> { false, false, true };
var secondList = new List<bool> { true };

for(int i =0; i < firstList.Count; i++)
{
    var currentItem = firstList[i];

    // If the item in the first list is true, then we need to insert it into the second list
    if(currentItem)
    {
        // If the second list is shorter than the actual index,
        // we insert missing elements so we can be able to insert the matching true in first list 
        // at the exact same position in second list.
        while(secondList.Count < i)
        {
            // Inserting false as you ask
            secondList.Add(false);
        }

        // Now the second list has at at least enough elements, 
        // we can insert true at the exact same location. 
        // Note that this will shift all other elements after that index
        secondList.Insert(i, currentItem);
    }
}
```

And the result:

```
foreach(var item in secondList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);    
}

// true    <- already in the second list at the begining
// false   <- added by default because there was no element in 2nd position
// true    <- added because in the first list
```

Note that if you want to replace an existing value at the same position, you need to use this code (notice the **i+1** in the **while condition** and the use of the **setter indexer** with the secondList:

```
while(secondList.Count < i+1)
{
    secondList.Add(false);
}

secondList[i] = currentItem;
```